# Lazy loading in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an issue with the lazy loading behavior in EntityFramework 5. Here are my two models

```
public class Person {
 [Key]
 [Required]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public int? OfficeID { get; set; }

 [ForeignKey("OfficeID ")]
 public virtual Offices OfficeID_Offices { get; set; }
}

public class Offices
{
[Key]
[Required]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
    //Navigation  Properties
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Person_OfficeID { get; set; }
```

}

Then I have the following function in my Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public Person Read(int intID)
    {
        Person objData = (from obj in objDB.Persons
                               where obj.ID == intID && !obj.Deleted
                               select obj).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

This controller method is called through a jquery $.Ajax call, which returns a JSON object. Since my foreign key OfficeID_Offices is virtual, I'd expect to only be loaded when I demand it explicitely. However when I look at my returned JSON Object, I can see that the entire Offices object is returned as well.

Lazy loading seems to be enabled in my DbContext, so I'm wondering how I could avoid having the whole Office object returned.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you using to view the JSON object? Because you might be triggering the call to the database to grab the object. Also, is it returning the actual object, or is it a dynamic proxy of that object?

Comment: It is returning the actual object, so  JSON representation of all the Offices properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization of the entity object(s) accesses the property which triggers lazy loading.  To disable lazy loading, set the `objDB.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` property to `False`

Comment: That would make sense. So basically you're saying I cannot use lazy loading? What are my alternatives if I want the Offices object returned only on demand?

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking

Comment: If lazy loading is set to false, won't my Offices object always be returned? So, the same behavior I have now right now?

Comment: No, the collection will be empty/null unless you explicitly populate it via eager loading methods or manually

Comment: Ok, I will look into eager loading. Thank you!